# postgresql replace symbol for store function variable?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I find '#' can replace some string in posgresql like:

```
SELECT
    'Record #' || i
FROM
    generate_series(1, 1000) i;
```

The symbol '#' can replace the by i, in this SQL commands.

I want to do similar like this for function like

```
SELECT lo_unlink('#') || i  
From
    SELECT picture i FROM image where belong_to = 254;
```

Of course '#' there is grammar error around '#', I just want to know any placehold grammar or symbol can work in function parameter like it replace string mark '#'

Answer (score 0):

The symbol `#` is **not** replaced, you are concatenating a number to a string containing this symbol.

This concatenation can occur anywhere, including when building a function parameter:

```sql
SELECT lo_unlink('#' || i)
From
    SELECT picture i FROM image where belong_to = 254;
```

which, if `i` is number 1, will create (and call) `lo_unlink('#1')`

so you may want to use `i` directly:

```sql
SELECT lo_unlink(i)
From
    SELECT picture i FROM image where belong_to = 254;
```

which, if `i` is number 1, will create (and call) `lo_unlink(1)`